# Empty Chooser with ActionSend Intent in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-android-player

I'm using Xamarin to create a simple Android application. I want to display a `ListView` to the user and when an item is clicked a `Chooser` is displayed to send some text to another application (e.g. SMS, email). I've got the `ListView` working, but when an item is clicked the `Chooser` that is displayed doesn't have any options; it just shows the `Chooser` header. I'm using the Xamarin Android Player, and I've tried with different versions of Android. Any idea what the problem is?

```cs
        this.ListView.ItemClick += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
            sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.SetType("text/plain");
            StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(sendIntent, "Share With..."));
        };
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. It is the Android Emulator that is the problem since you do not appear to have Send-enabled Apps installed, thus the empty list.

i.e. On a GenyMotion emulator with GApps installed, your code produces:

[image]

#### Either:

1) Test on a physical device that has one or more  "**send enabled**" apps installed

#### Or:

2) Install Google Play on your Xamarin's emulator instance and install some apps

- [Installing Google Play Services in XAP](https://university.xamarin.com/resources/how-to-install-google-play-on-android-emulator)